# Redirect cout to file c++

Tags: c++, redirect, cout

I have a problem with my code. It has been a small school project, that I wish to enhance by redirecting the strings from a console window, into a ".txt" file. My problem is that I only get the last string printet. So my guess is I keep overwriting the CoolNumber.txt file, but I cannot see where to make the change, so i don't overwrite, but just add to the file.

My code looks like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string intToChar[10] = { 
    "0",
    "1",
    "2abc",
    "3def",
    "4ghi",
    "5jkl",
    "6mno",
    "7pqrs",
    "8tuv",
    "9wxyz"
    };

void CoolNumber(string number, string character)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("CoolNumber.txt");
    streambuf* sbuf = cout.rdbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());

    if (number == "")
    {
        cout << character << ", " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int length = intToChar[number[0]-'0'].size();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            stringstream ss; 
            char c = intToChar[number[0]-'0'][i];
            string s;
            ss << c;
            ss >> s; 
            CoolNumber(number.substr(1, number.size()), character + s);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    string number = "27529250";

    cout << "Type your mobilenumber: ";
    cin >> number;
    //int length = intToChar[5].length();
    //cout << length << endl;
    CoolNumber(number, "");
}
```

I know my code works by cout to a console window, if it is written without this code

```
    ofstream file;
    file.open("CoolNumber.txt");
    streambuf* sbuf = cout.rdbuf();
    cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
```

It would be awesome to get this code to work.

P.s. I have tried looking at other topics here on StackOverflow, but can't seem to find any that works any better for me.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve anyway. Can't you just output to the file stream?

Comment: In each recursive call you're opening the file for writin gagain, clearing it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this which is the stream version of appending to a file

file.open("CoolNumber.txt", std::ofstream::app)

Answer (score 0):

The whole concept of redirecting `cout` is a bad idea. It will, for example, mean that if you call some other function in your code that wishes to write to `cout` for debug purposes, it goes to your file instead - which was probably not what you wanted.

Alter your function profile to be like this:

```
void CoolNumber(string number, string character, ostream& out = cout)
```

(Do add `out` as the argument to `CoolNumber` recursive call, as otherwise the inner call will use `cout` as the output, which is probably not what you want)

and then use `out` instead of `cout`. Then add:

```
ofstream file("CoolNumber.txt");

CoolNumber(number, "", file);
```

to `main`.

Or you could perhaps return a vector of strings from your function, and print them - following the principle of "do one thing, and do it well" - your current function mixes the calculation and the output, which is essentially doing two things.